# Is it possible to run pylint with ignore of "# pylint: disable=" instructions?

Tags: python, pylint

In order to identify smelly code I'd like to run `pylint` as if there were no `# pylint: disable=*` instructions (e.g. `pylint: disable=broad-except`).

Is it possible to disable `disable` itself on command line?

Of course I could create a temporary file with all `# pylint: disable` instructions removed but maybe `pylint` is smart enough to have this built in..

Comment: I think that search of all '# pylint: disable=' in the code will give you all 'smelly code' that your are looking for. You can use commands to search in folders like Ctrl+Shift+F in PyCharm or similar in your IDE

Comment: If you have `useless-suppression` enabled, so every "disable" is a necessary one, a search for `# pylint: disable=` will find exactly the same results as running pylint with the disable directive ignored...

Comment: And a related warning will give exactly what's asked: `suppressed-message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get these by enabling `suppressed-message`

```
pylint --enable=suppressed-message
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does _not_ disable disabled messages since a suppressed message seemingly has no negative score so you can still get 10/10 points with a suppressed message like `except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-except` but after all I can analyze the message now.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/faq.html#pylint-gave-my-code-a-negative-rating-out-of-ten-that-can-t-be-right) the score formula can be configured, although I'm not sure where it's documented how the configuration can be done.

Comment: Use the [`--evaluation` option](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/user_guide/output.html?highlight=evaluation#score-section) to configure the score evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the following could help:

- `pylint --enable=locally-disabled module.py`
- `pylint --enable=suppressed-message module.py`
- `pylint --enable=all module.py`

Answer (score -2):

I dont how to disable pylint but i know how to override it's default settings, like this-

1. In Your Working Directory create a file called `.pylintrc`
2. Done!, For Example-

```
[FORMAT]
max-line-length=1000 -To override the default line length which is 100
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question